# What is a HASH TABLE when doing HASH JOIN?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, oracle9i

In HASH JOIN method of oracle, HASH TABLE will be built on one of the tables and other will be joined depending on the values in the hash table.

Could you please let me know what is Hash table? What is the structure of hash table? how will it be created?

Comment: I don't know of anywhere that the internal hash table structure is documented.  [Here](http://koenigocm.blogspot.com/2012/01/join-techniques-concepts-in-oracle.html) is good starting paper on join techniques.  Good luck.

Comment: Tom Kyte has a nice presentation in swf format in his file download area (hj.swf/hj.zip) http://asktom.oracle.com

Comment: Thanks for the response Bob and Peter...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash table is a table where you can store stuff by the use of a key. It is like an array but stores things differently

```
a('CanBeVarchar') := 1; -- A hash table
```

In oracle, they are called [associative arrays or index by tables.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm) and you make one like this:

```
TYPE aHashTable IS TABLE OF [number|varchar2|user-defined-types] INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
myTable aHashTable;
```

So, what is it? it's just a bunch of key-value pairs. The data is stored as a linked list with head nodes that group the data by the use of something called HashCode to find things faster. Something like this:

```
a    ->     b     ->    c
Any         Bitter      Class
Array       Bold        Count
```

Say you are storing random words and it's meaning (a dictionary); when you store a word that begins with a, it is stored in the 'a' group. So, say you want this `myTable('Albatroz') := 'It's a bird'`, the hash code will be calculated and put in the A head node, where it belongs: just above the 'Any'. `a`, has a link to Any, which has a link to Array and so on.

Now, the cool thing about it is that you get fast data retreival, say you want the meaning of `Count`, you do this `definition := myTable('Count');` It will ignore searching for Any, Array, Bitter, Bold. Will search directly in the C head node, going trhough Class and finally Count; that is fast!

Here a wikipedia Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Note that my example is oversimplified read with a little bit of more detail in the link.

Read more details like the load factor: What happens if i get a LOT of elements in the a group and few in the b and c; now searching for a word that begins with a is not very optinmal, is it? the hash table uses the load factor to reorganize and distribute the load of each node, for example, the table can be converted to subgroups:

From this

```
a          b     ->    c
Any        Bitter      Class
Anode      Bold        Count
Anti       
Array
Arrays
Arrow
```

To this

```
an    ->   ar      b     ->    c
Any        Array   Bitter      Class
Anode      Arrays  Bold        Count
Anti       Arrow
```

Now looking for words like `Arrow` will be faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roger for a detailed explanation. It did help me understand the concept...:)

Comment: The hash tables used by Oracle in implementing a hash join are going to be different then associative arrays and index by tables. For one thing, Oracle can spill its hash tables to disk, with neither associated arrays nor index by tables support. (Unless you count OS level virtual memory.)

Comment: @ShannonSeverance You are welcome to edit my answer to add information, I really didn't cover the topic on what is done in a hash join, but i **dare to guess** that, as you get fast search in a hash table, oracle stores information of some inline view or whatever in a memory hash table to make later a join.